# Is there a word or phrase for running away from your wife or family because of their illness?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm trying to think if there is a specific word, term or phrase for running away from you wife or family because of their illness.

For example, the wife has Alzheimer's, and the husband runs away because he can't look after her any more.

I don't know if there is a word but I'm trying to use it for a title. It would be nice if I could find one or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

"Abandonment" might fit. It's the U.S. [legal term](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK98799/) at least.

From the New Jersey state legal code:

> 2C:24-8. Abandonment, neglect of elderly person, disabled adult; third degree crime
>
> 1. a. A person having a legal duty to care for or who has assumed continuing responsibility for the care of a person 60 years of age or older or a disabled adult, who abandons the elderly person or disabled adult or unreasonably neglects to do or fails to permit to be done any act necessary for the physical or mental health of the elderly person or disabled adult, is guilty of a crime of the third degree. For purposes of this section "abandon" means the willful desertion or forsaking of an elderly person or disabled adult.

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***[ditch](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ditch)***

> End a relationship with (someone) peremptorily

[Oxford Dictionaries Online]

**Usage:**

> Mary's husband ***ditched*** her because he no longer could take care of her dementia related illness and related expenses.